# Query object with RealmSwift but method will never be executed

Tags: ios, swift, generics, switch-statement, realm

Now I want query Result with different object(using generic)
I create `DataType` enum to handle different status

```
enum DataType{
    case Case
    case Product
    case Category
    case Composition
}
```

and query fuction called `query<T:Object>`

```
    func query<T:Object>(type: DataType,id: Int,complete: @escaping (_ success:Bool,_ results:Results<T>?,_ error:String?) -> ()) {

        switch type {
        case .Case:
            guard let caseResult = realm.objects(Case.self).filter("id = \(id)") as? Results<T> else {
                complete(false ,nil ,"Query case failed.")
                return
            }
            complete(true ,caseResult,nil)
            return
        case .Category:
            guard let categoryResult = realm.objects(Category.self).filter("id = \(id)") as? Results<T> else {
                complete(false ,nil ,"Query category failed.")
                return
            }
            complete(true ,categoryResult,nil)
            return
        case .Product:
            guard let productResult = realm.objects(Product.self).filter("id = \(id)") as? Results<T> else {
                complete(false ,nil ,"Query category failed.")
                return
            }
            complete(true ,productResult,nil)
            return
        case .Composition:
            guard let compositionResult = realm.objects(Composition.self).filter("id = \(id)") as? Results<T> else {
                complete(false ,nil ,"Query category failed.")
                return
            }
            complete(true ,compositionResult,nil)
            return
        }
    }
```

But when I created this fuction, and Xcode said

> Will never be execut

It means the closure can never execute from this fuction?
Can anyone help with this problem?Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure about error? I copypasted code to the xcode and got nothing.

Comment: You code compiles just find for me, it doesn't produce any errors or warnings. Some generic advise about your code: why use a closure to return values from a synchronous function? You also shouldn't use String interpolation in NSPredicates (Realm's filter uses predicates), but you should use the following predicate syntax: `.filter("id = %@",id)`.